# ApacheBench result to a file

Tags: linux, bash, load-testing, apachebench

I would like to save ApacheBench (ab) tool on linux to a file. When I run it with -v 2 it displays some results in my ssh window. How to move these data into a file and make sure that it will not display on ssh no more? I've tried > file.txt but it does not work and still display data in my ssh window.

Comment: Crossposted here: http://serverfault.com/questions/112516/apachebench-result-to-a-file

Comment: please mark as not for stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting "2>&1" after "> file.txt".

Comment: This didn't work for me. Using MacOS terminal.

Answer (score 6):

You can follow the below code.

```
ab -k -n 2000 -c 10 -g Example.txt http://www.example.com/ >ExampleResult.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: while the user could look at the man page to find the flags it is nice when the answer has a bit of explanation.

Comment: This worked for me on the Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If on MacOS you can also copy the output to the clipboard directly.

```
# MacOS copies result to clipboard
ab -k -n 2000 -c 10 http://www.example.com/ 2>&1 | pbcopy
```